# Call procedure not working php

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a basic form and a stored procedure to insert data. The 
connection to the database test successfully, but when i complete the form 
and i get this error:

> -Connection failed: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobbob' in 'where clause' .

Here is some of my code.

```
<html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Register</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?PHP
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $username = $_REQUEST['username'];
    $password= $_REQUEST['password'];
    $forename = $_REQUEST['forename'];
    $surname = $_REQUEST['surname'];
    $address_line1 = $_REQUEST['address_line1'];
    $address_line2 = $_REQUEST['address_line2'];
    $address_line3 = $_REQUEST['address_line3'];
    $city = $_REQUEST['city'];
    $postcode = $_REQUEST['postcode'];
    $phone = $_REQUEST['phone'];
    $email = $_REQUEST['email'];    

    $servername = "localhost";

     $dbusername = "user";
     $dbpassword = "password";
     $dbname = "library";

    try {

 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $dbusername,     
 $dbpassword);

 $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    echo "Connected successfully";   

   $sql1="select user_id from users where username=$username";   
 $result=$conn->query($sql1);
 if (empty($result[0])) { 

$sql ="CALL add_user(['forename'], ['surname'], ['address_line1'], 
['address_line2'], ['address_line3'], ['city'], ['postcode'], ['phone'], 
['email'],['username'], ['password'])";
 $conn->db_query($sql);   
 $conn = null;
     } else {
echo "Username taken";
     }
    }  catch(PDOException $e) {
 echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
 }
}
?>         

    <div>
    <form action="registrationpage.php" method="post">
    First Name: <input type="text" name="forename"> <br />
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="surname"> <br />
    Address_line1: <input type="text" name="address_line1"><br />
    Address_line2: <input type="text" name="address_line2"><br />
    Address_line3: <input type="text" name="address_line3"><br />
    City: <input type="text" name="city"><br />
    Postcode: <input type="text" name="postcode"><br />
    Phone <input type="text" name="phone"><br />
    Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br />
    Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br />
    Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br />
    Confirm Password: <input id="password" type="password" name="password"> 
  <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Register" name="submit">

    </form>
    </div> 

    </body>
 </html>
```

How to solve this ?

Comment: Check your add_user stored procedure, search for jobbob in the where clause. Apparently it is missing or misspelled.

Comment: @pritaeas it probably calls/uses a column ```jobbob``` that does not exists in the database

Comment: is jobbob the username from your form ? shoudnt be $sql1="select user_id from users where username=$username"; something like $sql1='select user_id from users where username="$username"'; maybe also have a look for prepared statements

Comment: @H.J.Meijer Indeed what I meant, but failed to type correctly.

Comment: Please show your table structure. The error clearly states that your table doesn't contain a `jobbob` column.

Comment: Yes Jobbob was what I entered into the username field of my form.

Comment: then try $sql1='select user_id from users where username="$username"';

Comment: This is my stored procedure

Comment: your $sql1 results in select user_id from users where username=jobbob ; but you need : select user_id from users where username='jobbob'

Comment: Dear all thank you for all your comments.  In the end I realised that the stored procedure would only allow loggin as root by default and so when I was entering in the username it was overriding the procedure username of root hence failing.  It's all working now and thank you for taking the time to assist.